# How to determine the positive class in roc_auc_score?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, auc

I want to use `roc_auc_score` to evaluate the performance of the classifier, but I'm not sure what is the right parameters to give it.

This is a description of this function in the documentation: [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Ihv.png).

As you can see, it needs `y_score`, which is the probability estimates of the positive class, but **how to determine which class is positive? For example, when I use `predict_proba`, which column should I use?**

Now the way I use this function is as follows:

```
       clf = SVC(                    
            kernel = 'linear',
            probability = True,  
            random_state = 1 )

       clf.fit(train,train_Labels)

       score = np.array(clf.predict_proba(test_values))
       auc = roc_auc_score(test_Labels,score[:,1])
```

`train_Labels` and `test_Labels` are one-dimensional vectors with `0` in front and `1` behind：`[0,0,0,1,1,1]`.

In train and test, one row represents a sample, and one column represents a feature.

It might not be appropriate to use `predict_proba`, but there are special requirements in my project, so don't worry.

**I want to know if the vectors I passed into the `roc_auc_score` function as a positive probability is correct(`y_true` and `y_score`).**

If there is anything unclear about the question, please ask me, I am a novice, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

I have one shortcut and one answer:

## The shortcut.

You may use the function make_scorer from sklearn to create a more "robust" roc_auc_score.
Here is the complete example :

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import numpy

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2, random_state=1)
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
model.fit(X, y)
```

```py
model.predict_proba(X)
```

results in :

```
array([[0.2022794 , 0.7977206 ],
       [0.78449699, 0.21550301],
       [0.87371492, 0.12628508],
       ...,
       [0.19976995, 0.80023005],
       [0.00463778, 0.99536222],
       [0.93405707, 0.06594293]])
```

You can create your own roc_auc_score by doing:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
roc_auc_scorer = make_scorer(
    roc_auc_score, 
    needs_proba=True,
)
```

Therefore

```py
roc_auc_scorer(model, X, y)
```

returns

```
0.9246156984627939
```

## Now the more formal answer

From sklearn documentation :

> y_score
>
> [ ... ] scores must be the scores of the class with the greater label

(source https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html)

and predict_proba returns :

> T array-like of shape (n_samples, n_classes)
>
> Returns the probability of the sample for each class in the model, where classes are ordered as they are in self.classes_.

(source LogisticRegression, might not be true for every clf ! https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba)

Given that, from my understanding, you can determine "the greater label" and therefore which column you should use.
From the previous example :

and:

```py
model.classes_
```

has been set to:

```
array([0, 1])
```

So using numpy.argmax you can get the position of `the class with the greater label` and get the roc_auc_score:

```py
_idx = numpy.argmax(model.classes_)
_p = model.predict_proba(X)[:,_idx]
roc_auc_score(y, _p)
```

results:

```
0.9246156984627939
```

I hope this may help !

Answer (score -1):

As I understand correctly you want to get the roc_auc_score for your binary classification problem.

There is no need for you to rearrange the score function, you can only use:

```
auc = roc_auc_score(test_labels, score)
```

As based on the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html):

> y_score array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_classes)
>
> ```
> Target scores. In the binary and multilabel cases, these can be either probability estimates or non-thresholded decision values (as
> ```
>
> returned by decision_function on some classifiers). In the multiclass
>   case, these must be probability estimates which sum to 1. The binary
>   case expects a shape (n_samples,), and the scores must be the scores
>   of the class with the greater label.

Which fits to your problem.

The shape of `test.labels.shape`and `score.shape`should match.

Comment: ,thank you for your reply.In addition, I haven't rearranged the labels, the training set and the test set class labels were originally 0 followed by 1.So there's no problem with my usage, is there?I think this is the right way to use it:`       clf = SVC(                    
            kernel = 'linear',
            probability = True,  
            random_state = 1 )

       clf.fit(train,train_Labels)

       score = np.array(clf.decision_function(test_values))
       auc = roc_auc_score(test_Labels,score)`     Do you agree with me?

Comment: try it, it should be fine